# JPL/SWI Prolog not working

Tags: java, eclipse, path, swi-prolog

I'm trying to use the SWI-Prolog JPL library, but I'm having problems.

I'm trying to let my Eclipse project access JPL, but when I try to start the program, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jpl in java.library.path
```

I copied the jpl.jar into my project directory, and I set it on the build path. Additionally, I pass the following VM arguments:

```
-Djava.library.path="C:\Program Files\Prolog\bin"
```

(That's the directory where Prolog was installed).

What am I doing wrong?

---

EDIT: I don't seem to have the libpl.dll anywhere on my computer. Could this be causing my problem?

Comment: "libjpl.dll" should be in "bin" directory

Comment: It is not.

I think this is the problem. I'm going to try to find an older version of Prolog that has the correct libraries for JPL to work.

Comment: Sorry I am Unix-centric. For Windows, the file you need is "jpl.dll". For Unix, it is "libjpl.so". There is no "libjpl.dll" to look for on Windows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `jvm.dll` of your running JDK/JRE must be available in your system `PATH` so that `jpl.dll` from `java.library.path` loads properly.

You have to take care to 32 bits / 64 bits consistency between your JPL installation and your running JVM - so do not try any mix.

Here is information from an old [installation doc](http://www.swi-prolog.org/packages/jpl/installation.html).

For such installation support, you should use the JPL mailing list.

Comment: That JPl 3.x seems like a good idea, is there a download link somewhere?

Comment: The important information from the link is the setup process and requirements, not really the version itself. By the way, the page is really out-dated: 2004... What version do you use ? Where does it come from ? JPL project seems gone.

Comment: I installed the latest version of Prolog. It contained the jpl.jar and jpl.dll, but it does not include libpl.dll, so I'm thinking that is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the `java.library.path` to the folder where the jpl.dll file is located. As far as I know it is the `Prolog\bin` folder.

Comment: Progress! That changes the output to this: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files\Prolog\bin\jpl.dll: Can't find dependent libraries

Comment: Try to add your Prolog\bin folder to the PATH environment variable as well. It seems that the java.library.path settings does not apply for another dll loading from a dll file.

Comment: Hmm. That doesn't change anything.

What are the required libraries that JPL needs to run?

Answer (score 0):

A system-wide solution in a Mac environment (SWI-Prolog version 7.1.4 for x86_64-darwin13.1.0) would be to create the following symlink:

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/swi-prolog/7.1.4/libexec/lib/swipl-7.1.4/lib/x86_64-darwin13.1.0/libjpl.jnilib /Library/Java/Extensions/libjpl.jnilib
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be rather

> ln -s
>   /Applications/SWI-Prolog.app/Contents/swipl/lib/x86_64-darwin/libjpl.dylib
>   /Library/Java/Extensions/libjpl.dylib

? (no .inilib was found under darwin folder)

In my case still error on mojave (SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 8.0.2)):

Jan 03, 2020 12:10:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [ACTIONS] in context with path [/SVIZ] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Applications/SWI-Prolog.app/Contents/swipl/lib/x86_64-darwin/libjpl.dylib: dlopen(/Applications/SWI-Prolog.app/Contents/swipl/lib/x86_64-darwin/libjpl.dylib, 1): Library not loaded: @rpath/libswipl.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/SWI-Prolog.app/Contents/swipl/lib/x86_64-darwin/libjpl.dylib
  **Reason: image not found**